# MySQL Enterprise Monitor Installation Error: MySQL Instance

Tags: mysql

I am trying to set up MySQL Enterprise Monitor on a RHEL8 server with MySQL 8.0.22 Enterprise Edition.
I hit this error:

> Blockquote
> Error running /opt/mysql/enterprise/monitor/mysql/bin/mysql
> --defaults-file=/opt/mysql/enterprise/monitor/mysql/my.cnf -S  /opt/mysql/enterprise/monitor/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock -u root -D mysql -e

> "DELETE  FROM user WHERE user = 'root' AND host NOT IN ('localhost',
> '127.0.0.1'); ALTER  USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '****';
> UPDATE user SET User =  'service_manager' WHERE User = 'root'; DELETE
> FROM user WHERE User = ''; FLUSH  PRIVILEGES;":

> /opt/mysql/enterprise/monitor/mysql/bin/mysql: error while loading
> shared libraries: libtinfo.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No
> such file or  directory
>
> Press [Enter] to continue:

I was able to continue, but I am not able to load the MySQL Enterprise Monitor dashboard.
I have an existing instance on the server, but I chose bundled MySQL database in the installation.

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: the message says you are missing libtinfo.so.5 have you tried to install it

Comment: That solved it, thank you! I am still new to Linux, thought it's something to do with the mysql instance initialization. Thanks.